# How to improve the page loading speed in website

Tags: reactjs, performance, pagespeed

I have to rebuild a new page with ReactJS to improve the page loading speed.

The issues which I have to solve:

- Favicon - Currently loading spinner is displayed while the page is loading.
- Improve the whole page loading time

It would be great if we can show the favicon while the page is loading.

Any suggestions and answers are welcome!

Comment: Have you profiled your webpage to understand where the time is going? If the underlying problem is with content delivery (images, bad compression, etc.) then switching to a different front-end JavaScript library isn't going to do much.

Comment: use lighthouse extension to analyze your webpage to see where the time is going. what's your old stack? if you paste you lighthouse logs here we can help you more

Comment: Hey, @AmirTahani, would you like to send me lighthouse link?

Comment: @FrozenICE here it is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pingdom` tools to analyze your website performance.

In my case, large static files like images, audios took much time to load.

Typical `Pingdom` sites are like this.

https://www.pingdom.com/